I want to retrieve and display the data in the modal form after clicking the button
I am coding a project and I am using a modal form for registrations so I now want to display and modify the data in the modal, When I click on the edit button I get the data from the form in the console but I do not cannot display them in modal form.
in the 'domainedeformation_candidats' table I record the information with the user ID ($_SESSION['user_id'])
Code index.php :
<?php 
session_start(); 
require_once('../session.php');
require_once('../connexion.php');
// header('Content-Type: application/json');
$_SESSION['csrf_token'] = bin2hex(random_bytes(32));
?>
<body>
    <!-- Header End -->
    <?php
        // Supposons que $conn est votre objet PDO pour la connexion à la base de données
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM DomaineDeFormation_candidats WHERE ID_Candidat = :id_candidat");
        $stmt->bindParam(':id_candidat', $_SESSION['user_id']); // Assurez-vous que l'ID du candidat est disponible
        $stmt->execute();
        $formations = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    ?>

    <!-- Diplômes et Formations -->
    <div class="col-md-12 wow mt-2">
        <div class="bg-light rounded p-4">
            <div class="text">
                <div class="row">
                    <?php foreach ($formations as $formation): ?>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mb-3">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-3 espace_bordure">
                                <?= htmlspecialchars($formation['Mois_AnneeDebut']) ?> - <?= htmlspecialchars($formation['Mois_AnneeFin']) ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-8 espace_bordure">
                                <?= htmlspecialchars($formation['Diplome']) ?> - <?= htmlspecialchars($formation['DomaineDeFormation']) ?> - <?= htmlspecialchars($formation['Ecole']) ?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-1">                                                    
                                <a href="#" data-id="<?= htmlspecialchars($formation['ID']) ?>" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editeformation" onclick="fetchFormationData(this)" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                    <i class="bi bi-pen-fill"></i>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        
        
    <!-- Modale HTML (structure inchangée) -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="editeformation" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="editeformationLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="editeformationLabel">Modifier la Formation</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" id="formationModal" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                </div>
                <form action="submit_formation.php" method="post">
                    <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['csrf_token']); ?>">
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div id="formation-container" class="">
                            <div class="formation-item mb-3">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="mb-3 col-md-12">
                                        <label for="ecole_1" class="form-label">Établissement</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="ecole[]" id="ecole_1" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
                                        <label for="diplome_1" class="form-label">Diplôme</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="diplome[]" id="diplome_1" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
                                        <label for="domaineDeFormation_1" class="form-label">Domaine de formation</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="domaineDeFormation[]" id="domaineDeFormation_1" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <script>
                                        const htmlContent = `
                                            <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
                                                <label for="domaineDeFormation_1" class="form-label">Domaine de formation</label>
                                                <input type="text" name="domaineDeFormation[]" id="domaineDeFormation_1" class="form-control" required>
                                            </div>
                                        `;
                                    </script>
                                    <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
                                        <label for="moisanneedebut_1" class="form-label">Mois et Année de début</label>
                                        <input type="month" name="moisanneedebut[]" id="moisanneedebut_1" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-3 col-md-6">
                                        <label for="moisanneefin_1" class="form-label">Mois et Année de fin</label>
                                        <input type="month" name="moisanneefin[]" id="moisanneefin_1" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-3 col-md-12">
                                        <label for="competences_1" class="form-label">Mes Compétences</label>
                                        <input type="text" name="competences[]" id="competences_1" class="form-control" required>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="mb-3 col-md-12">
                                        <label for="descriptionPoste_1" class="form-label">Description</label>
                                        <textarea name="descriptionPoste[]" id="descriptionPoste_1" class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="border-radius: 18px;">Enregistrer</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


$('#editeformation').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    var formationId = $('#editeformation').data('formation-id');
    fetchFormationData(formationId);
});

function fetchFormationData(formationId) {
    console.log('Formation ID: ' + formationId);

    fetch('get_formation_data.php?id=' + formationId)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(responseText => {
            console.log('Texte de la réponse:', responseText);
            try {
                var data = JSON.parse(responseText);
                console.log('Données reçues:', data);

                // Mise à jour des champs du formulaire avec les données reçues
                $('#ecole_1').val(data.ecole || '');
                $('#diplome_1').val(data.diplome || '');
                $('#domaineDeFormation_1').val(data.domaineDeFormation || '');
                $('#moisanneedebut_1').val(data.moisanneedebut || '');
                $('#moisanneefin_1').val(data.moisanneefin || '');
                $('#competences_1').val(data.competences || '');
                $('#descriptionPoste_1').val(data.descriptionPoste || '');
                
                console.log('Données reçues - 5 :', data.descriptionPoste);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erreur lors de la conversion en JSON:', error);
                alert('Erreur lors de la récupération des données.');
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Erreur:', error);
            alert('Erreur lors de la requête : ' + error.message);
        });
}

get_formation_data.php
<?php
require '../connexion.php'; 

if (!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id'])) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'ID manquant']);
    exit();
}

$id = intval($_GET['id']);

error_log("ID recherché : " . $id);

try {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM domainedeformation_candidats WHERE ID = :id');
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->execute();

    $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if ($data) {
        echo json_encode($data);
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'Aucune donnée trouvée']);
    }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Erreur de base de données: ' . $e->getMessage()]);
}
?>


I tried this script to display the data in the Modal form but nothing is displayed however I retrieve it in the console:
function fetchFormationData(element) {
    var formationId = element.getAttribute('data-id');
    console.log('Formation ID: ' + formationId);

    fetch('get_formation_data.php?id=' + formationId)
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(responseText => {
            console.log('Texte de la réponse:', responseText);
            try {
                var data = JSON.parse(responseText);
                console.log('Données reçues:', data);

                // Test simple : mise à jour des champs avec des valeurs statiques
                document.getElementById('ecole_1').value = data.ecole || 'Valeur par défaut';
                document.getElementById('diplome_1').value = data.diplome || 'Valeur par défaut';
                document.getElementById('domaineDeFormation_1').value = data.domaineDeFormation || 'Valeur par défaut';
                document.getElementById('moisanneedebut_1').value = data.moisanneedebut || '2023-01';
                document.getElementById('moisanneefin_1').value = data.moisanneefin || '2023-12';
                document.getElementById('competences_1').value = data.competences || 'Compétence par défaut';
                document.getElementById('descriptionPoste_1').value = data.descriptionPoste || 'Description par défaut';
                
                console.log('Données ECOLE:', document.getElementById('moisanneefin_1').value);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Erreur lors de la conversion en JSON:', error);
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Erreur:', error);
            alert('Erreur : ' + error.message);
        });
}


What does "cannot" mean? Are there any JavaScript errors in the console after you fetch the data? What does responseText contain? I don't expect document.getElementById('ecole_1').value will work, for example, because there is no id="ecole_1" anywhere in your HTML

And what does console.log('Formation ID: ' + formationId); output? In your original code, var formationId = $('#editeformation').data('formation-id'); makes no sense because there is no such data-attribute on the edit form (and it wouldn't be sensible to have one). P.S. Don't use inline event handlers onclick="fetchFormationData(this), it just makes your code harlder to debug. Use jquery handlers, or document.addEventListener in your script area so you can see easily what events the JS is handling.

And what about the console.log('Données reçues:', data);, does that show the data structure you expected?

Are you facing problems with JS, with PHP, or with MySQL?

@ADyson
Here is the code correction using jquery:
try {
    var ecoleInput = document.getElementById('ecole_1');
    var diplomeInput = document.getElementById('diplome_1');
    ecoleInput.value = data.ecole || 'Valeur par défaut';
    diplomeInput.value = data.diplome || 'Valeur par défaut';
    ecoleInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
        console.log('Champ École:', this.value);
    });
    diplomeInput.addEventListener('input', function() {
        console.log('Champ:', this.value);
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error('Erreur:', error);
}


Please [edit] your question to show new code. That's unreadable the way you've presented it here! In the main post you can format it properly. And also what are you telling us? Do you mean it's working now, with that code? If that's your solution then add it as an Answer below. Either way it doesn't belong in these comments, which are just for people to briefly request clarifications, or make suggestions. The resulting information belongs in your posts. Take the [tour] if you don't understand how Stackoverflow works. Thanks.

@ADyson   I have not yet found a solution and currently I am following the example that you gave using jquery, So I brought the code back to the how to show you how I proceeded.

Ok, well then please edit your question to show it properly, please. And explain what result you are now getting when you use that. I don't see which bit of my suggestion that is supposed to cover, anyway - please clarify that.

Also it is more important for you to show us the responseText data you're seeing, as we originally requested.

@ADyson            Here is the response in the console that I copied
INS: successfully injected instart
index.php?ID_Emplois=9:751 Texte de la réponse: {"ID":"3","ID_Candidat":"9","Ecole":"CER","Diplome":"LIC","DomaineDeFormation":"IT","Mois_AnneeDebut":"2021-01","Mois_AnneeFin":"2024-06","Competences":"SDIO","DescriptionPoste":"Lorem,"}

Oh dear. Which bit of edit your question are you finding hard to understand? Stop putting data and code in the comments.

Anyway the main problem here is that JS property values are case-sensitive. ecole is not the same as Ecole. So if you write document.getElementById('ecole_1').value = data.Ecole || 'Valeur par défaut'; instead of document.getElementById('ecole_1').value = data.ecole || 'Valeur par défaut'; it will work. You also have other silly mistakes, like Mois_AnneeDebut is obviously not the same as moisanneedebut. Fix all that, and everything is fine - demo: https://jsfiddle.net/7oq1p09L/1/ . We could have told you that an hour ago if you'd shared the data when we first asked for it.
